# notation for accessing class and object attributes in python

Tags: python, oop, python-2.7, python-3.x

In the following code ;

```
>>> class fooo():
        def __init__(self):
            self.a=[]
>>> fooo().a
    []
>>> fooo.a
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<pyshell#12>", line 1, in <module>
        fooo.a
    AttributeError: class fooo has no attribute 'a'
```

i'm a little confuse about the notations fooo().a  and fooo.a for accessing the variable "a".Is it that whenever we use fooo().a a object of fooo() class is thrown and it is equivalent to doing as:

```
>>> m=fooo()
>>> m.a
[]
```

; while using the notation fooo.a , we are expecting a to be a class/static variable ? Is i'm right or it is something else?

Comment: Basically, yes.  You shouldn't think of `fooo().a` as a notation in itself; it's a combination of two separate things.  As in your second example `fooo()` on its own creates an instance.  Then `.a` accesses its attribute.

Answer (score 0):

`a` is an instance attribute. It can be accessed using `fooo().a`. But note that doing that just throws away the `fooo` instance created; a more sensible example is:

```
y = fooo()
y.a = 5
```

It doesn't exist until an instance of the class is created.  Yeah you are totally correct.